# AngularJs filter elements to parse

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using a `ng-repeat` on a dynamic list of messages which contain HTML elements. To display these elements, I use `ng-bind-html` and `$sce.trustAsHtml()`.

This works perfect, but `$sce.trustAsHtml()` parses every html-elements including scripts etc, but I only need things like `<img>,<br>,<i> or <b>` to parse. Is it possible to filter out elements that I dont need to be parsed?

Thanks!

### Update

Sorry I didn't give some code, but the problem is solved:

I included the script, added "ngSanitize" to `angular.module("name",[...,"ngSanitize"])`.

There was another problem: I binded the html from `$sce.trustAsHtml(message)`, but that isn't sanitized. Using just `ng-bind-html="message"` is enough!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should provide a fiddle. It's hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1 :

Use `strip_tags` php equivalent in javascript. ([**strip_tags**](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/))

```
   $sce.trustAsHtml( strip_tags($html, '<img><br><i><b>') );
```

### Option 2 :

You can use `ngSanitize` module. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the `$sanitize` service.

```
 angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/usbIMoiLS7bxZpRGQrxj?p=preview) demo

More info : [`$sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Comment: I tried to do that, but it gives an error: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=Portaal&p1=Error%3…F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D4.5.4_11%3A18%3A170)"

Comment: `ngSanitize` require `angular-sanitize.js` script.